# Slot machine game Phaser 3

Tags: animation, sprites, spritesheet, phaser

I need an advice on creating a slot machine phaser game.
So it looks like this

[image]

I need to plan an approach to do the animation of the reels of the slot machine. I have idea of using tileSprite, are there any other ideas of implementing this game?

Comment: How does your tileSprite idea work so far? Is there any specific problem with that solution you'd like us to focus on solving/improving? Or is it working adequately for your needs?

Comment: I have not done it with tile sprite because I have lack of experience and did not have time to focus on reading tileSprite documentation, so if you have any solution with tile sprite I would be pleased if you share. I have done it with rotating it by-hand. I change the y position of each sprite in update function and when a sprite reaches MAX Y position I update its Y to min Y, and so on, now I have another problem to stop the slot machine at some index of array.

Comment: Want to edit your question to clarify your stopping problem, and show how you've made it work so far with your hand rotation?